# Constructing a colimit

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, limits-colimits

Consider a functor $F: \mathcal{I} \rightarrow \textrm{Sets}$ where $\mathcal{I}$ is small. Then the colimit of $F$ is given by $\amalg_{i \in \textrm{Ob}(\mathcal{I})}F(i)/{\sim}$ where $\sim$ is the equivalence relation generated by: $x \in F(i) \sim y \in F(j)$ if there exist an $\alpha \in \textrm{Mor}_{\mathcal{I}}(i, j)$ such that $F(\alpha)(x) = y$.

I am trying to mimic the same argument to find the colimit of $F$ when $F: \mathcal{I} \rightarrow \textrm{AbelianGrps}$. My first guess was $S := \oplus_{i \in \textrm{Ob}(\mathcal{I})}F(i)/{\sim}$ where $\sim$ is defined as above. The problem is I don't think $S$ is even a group. Suppose $a, b \in S$, then there exists a representative element $r_{1}, r_{2}$ such that $a \sim r_{1}$ and $b \sim r_{2}$. Then there exists $\alpha_{1}, \alpha_{2}$ such that $F(\alpha_{1})(a) = r_{1}$ and $F(\alpha_{2})(b) = r_{2}$. This doesn't seem to tell me anything on what $a + b$ is equivalent to.

My next idea was that maybe the colimit is $\oplus_{i \in \textrm{Ob}(\mathcal{I})}F(i)/H$ for some subgroup $H$. Furthermore, $H$ needs to have the property that $x \in F(i)$, $y \in F(j)$ belong to the same coset of $\oplus_{i \in \textrm{Ob}(\mathcal{I})}F(i)/H$ when there exists an $\alpha \in \textrm{Mor}_{\mathcal{I}}(i, j)$ such that $F(\alpha)(x) = y$. How would I go about constructing such an $H$?

Comment: When "$\sim$" is used as a binary relation symbol, as in $a\sim b$, then it has the spacing before and after it that binary relation and binary operation symbols have.  In expressions like $\amalg_{i \in \textrm{Ob}(\mathcal{I})}F(i)/{\sim}$, it shouldn't have that extra spacing and the presence of the inappropriate spacing is conspicuous.  So I put it in braces: \amalg_{i \in \textrm{Ob}(\mathcal{I})}F(i)/{\sim}. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the construction of the colimit of sets, you have to define $\sim$ as the equivalence relation *generated* by the relation which you have defined.

Similarly, in order to construct the colimit of algebraic structures of any type, you have to define $\sim$ as the smallest [congruence relation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruence_relation) generated by the relation (this ensures that the quotient will be again an algebraic structure of the same type). In case of abelian groups, this means that $H$ is *generated* by elements of the form $y-F(\alpha)(x)$ where $x \in F(i)$ and $y \in F(j)$ and $\alpha : i \to j$. The quotient by $H$ has clearly the desired universal property of a colimit.

Notice that all this is a special case of the general result that colimits may be constructed via coequalizers and coproducts.

Comment: Is there a reference for this general result that you mention?

Comment: Every book on category theory (Mac Lane, Kashiwara-Schapira, Borceux, ...). In Mac Lane it's in Section V.2. See also Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_%28category_theory%29#Existence_of_limits

Comment: Why does this choice of $H$ make the diagram for the co-cone from $F \rightarrow \oplus_{i \in \textrm{Ob}\mathcal{I}}F(i)/H$ commute? That is, suppose $\alpha: i \rightarrow j$ and $F(\alpha): F(i) \rightarrow F(j)$. Let $\psi_{i}: F(i) \rightarrow \oplus_{i \in \textrm{Ob}\mathcal{I}}F(i)/H$ be the inclusion map and similarly define $\psi_{j}$. Why does $F(\alpha)(x) = x$ (in the quotient group) for $x \in F(i)$?

Comment: This is precisely by the construction of the quotient group and of $H$. Recall that the purpose of quotient groups is to make things equal (or zero, in particular). (The coset-mania distracts from this basic idea.)